# How to scan SD card for particular extension of files in android?

Tags: android, sd-card, documents

I am working on a project which contains a module to scan pdf, doc xls files from sd card and make list of them. I also want to make list of folders only.

As I am very new to android. Anyone have idea of achieving this.

Here is my code:

```
public class MediaScannerWrapper implements  
MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {
    private MediaScannerConnection mConnection;
    private String mPath;
    private String mMimeType;

    // filePath - where to scan; 
    // mime type of media to scan i.e. "image/jpeg". 
    // use "*/*" for any media
    public MediaScannerWrapper(Context ctx, String filePath, String mime){
        mPath = filePath;
        mMimeType = mime;
        mConnection = new MediaScannerConnection(ctx, this);
    }

    // do the scanning
    public void scan() {
        mConnection.connect();
    }

    // start the scan when scanner is ready
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mConnection.scanFile(mPath, mMimeType);
        Log.w("MediaScannerWrapper", "media file scanned: " + mPath);
    }

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        // when scan is completes, update media file tags
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
public void walkdir(File dir) {
    String pdfPattern = ".pdf";

    File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
              if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pdfPattern)){
                              //Do what ever u want

              }
            }
        }
    }    }
```

To search on the whole sdcard call this function using`walkdir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());`

Comment: Your code rocks. Can we also list all folders only by this and all files present in SD card. Please Help.

Comment: This code will blow up if there is a symbolic link in path.

Answer (score 2):

Use [getExternalStorageDirectory ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to get the SD card path. (Do not hardcode it)

Loop through each subfolder, and check files names with your desired extension. Use String [endswith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method to check if file name ends with the extension.

[Here's a sample code](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-find-files-with-certain-extension-only/) that might help you.

Answer (score 2):

I advice using  [`commons.io`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library which handles symbolic links and extension resolution as well.

Task to scan for files with extensions:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ScanTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ScanTask.Result> {

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(String... extensions) {

        if(extensions == null){
            extensions = new String[0];
        }

        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        boolean success = false;
        String status = "";

        if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            try {
                files.addAll(FileUtils.listFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), extensions, true));
                success = true;
                status = "ok";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MyApp","File error:",e);
                success = false;
                status = "Scan error";
            }
        }else {
            success = false;
            status = "External storage not available";
        }


        return new Result(success,status,files);
    }

    public static class Result{
        public final boolean success;
        public final String message;
        public final List<File> files;

        public Result(boolean success, String message,List<File> files) {
            this.success = success;
            this.message = message;
            this.files = files;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
   ScanTask task = new ScanTask(){
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.success){
                List<File> files = result.files;
                //--do something with files--
            }else {
                String error = result.message;
                //--do something with error message--
            }
        }
    };

    task.execute("mp3","jpeg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:
here is the [link](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/07/display-more-than-one-extension-files.html).

```
/**
  * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
  * */
//you can choose the filter for me i put .mp3
class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".pdf" ) || name.endsWith(".docs" )) || name.endsWith(".3gp" ) ;
    }
}
```