# How to periodically scan SD card for files of a particular type?

Tags: android, sd-card, android-mediascanner

Hi I am pretty new to android and am working on an app that needs to scan the SD card for ppt and pdf files and upload them to Google Drive.

I have implemented a **MediaScannerConnectionClient** class (in a similar way to the code in this question [How to scan SD card for particular extension of files in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800667/how-to-scan-sd-card-for-particular-extension-of-files-in-android)) that scans and returns the file once when **scanFile** is called.

However I need to be able to upload the files that are added to the SD card even after my app has been started and **scanFile** has been called.

Is there any way to do this besides calling **scanFile** continuously after a fixed time interval ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sending broadcast saying External storage mounted :/

Comment: Run that service after a constant interval e.g. using `AlarmManger`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, thanks